# JS: sort the value of 0 to last element

Tags: javascript

how do I make the items

from this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Honda,
    inventory: 5,
  },
{
    name: 'Lambo',
    inventory: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    inventory: 10,
  },
  
]
```

to this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Honda,
    inventory: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    inventory: 10,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lambo',
    inventory: 0,
  },
]
```

this code doesn't sort as expected:

```
const newItems = [...items].sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.inventory === b.inventory) return 0;
        
                if (a.inventory === 0) return 1;
                
                return -1;
            });

            console.log(newItems);
```

result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Toyota",
        "inventory": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Honda",
        "inventory": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Lambo",
        "inventory": 0
    }
]
}
```

notice the Toyota is on the first instead of second.
I want to only put the inventory of 0 to last element. currently it sorts descending (10-0) which is not how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the difference of whether one or the other items being iterated over is 0.

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Honda',
    inventory: 5,
  },
{
    name: 'Lambo',
    inventory: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    inventory: 10,
  }, 
]
const newItems = [...items].sort((a, b) => (a.inventory === 0) - (b.inventory === 0));
console.log(newItems);
```

If you want to sort the rest in ascending order (without respect to the original sort order), then take the difference of the plain `.inventory`s after that.

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Honda',
    inventory: 5,
  },
{
    name: 'Lambo',
    inventory: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Toyota',
    inventory: 10,
  }, 
]
const newItems = [...items].sort((a, b) =>
  (a.inventory === 0) - (b.inventory === 0)
  || a.inventory - b.inventory
);
console.log(newItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the sort callback, when `a` is found to be zero, make it sort *after* `b`; and vice-versa:

- When `a` is zero `return 1` means `a` is after `b`.
- When `b` is zero `return -1` means `a` is before `b`.

This would also work.

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "Honda",
    inventory: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "Lambo",
    inventory: 0,
  },
  {
    name: "Toyota",
    inventory: 10,
  },
];

const newItems = [...items].sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.inventory === 0) return 1;

  if (b.inventory === 0) return -1;

  if (a.inventory < b.inventory) return -1;

  if (a.inventory > b.inventory) return 1;

  if (a.inventory === b.inventory) return 0;
});

console.log(newItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use baby steps approach for this:

1️⃣ get the items that have 0 inventory

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "Honda",
    inventory: 5,
  },
  {
    name: "Lambo",
    inventory: 0,
  },
  {
    name: "Toyota",
    inventory: 10,
  },
];

const zeroInventoryArray = items.filter(item => item.inventory === 0)
/*
[
  {
    "name": "Lambo",
    "inventory": 0
  }
]
*/
```

2️⃣ get the items that have inventory different from 0 and sort them

```js
const items = [
      {
        name: "Honda",
        inventory: 5,
      },
      {
        name: "Lambo",
        inventory: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Toyota",
        inventory: 10,
      },
    ];

    const nonZeroInventoryArray = items.filter(item => item.inventory !== 0).sort((a,b) => a.inventory - b.inventory)

/*
[
  {
    "name": "Honda",
    "inventory": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "inventory": 10
  }
]
*/
```

3️⃣ merge the results so the 0 inventory items come at the end

```js
const result = [...nonZeroInventoryArray, ...zeroInventoryArray]
```

➡️ Sure, this is not very fancy, but I think it adds clarity and makes the code easy to be understood by any-level developer.